# Image does not load using javafx.scene.image.Image when passing location string to the constructor

Tags: image, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I am following the turorial below:
(**using javafx 20.0.1 and open jdk 20.0.1 --> intellij IDE and Maven build tool**)

[JavaFX Tutorial Part 4: CSS Styling](https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/part4/)

At the last part of the tutorial I need to set icon to the scene.

I have followed what is written on the instruction but the image deos not show.

Here is my file structure:

[image: Project File Structure]

Here is the code:

`this.primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:images/86957_address_book_icon.png"));`

I have noticed that, in the constructor before the location of the image (images/86957_address_book_icon.png) the following was written:

*file:*

I am new to java and javafx in general. Not sure what is this.

Tried without *file:* and the following error was thrown:

```
Exception in Application start method
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
...
...
```

I have tried the following location strings:

added `/` --> **"file:/images/86957_address_book_icon.png"**

full path --> **"file:com/adnan/addressapp/images/86957_address_book_icon.png"**

## absolute path --> **ONLY THEN IT WORKED**

But this is not the solution I want or need.

Could you please help?

Comment: CodeMakery tutorials are usually good, but using a hardcoded `file:` URL there is absolute nonsense. (No matter what path you use, it could never work once the application is bundled as a jar file, for example.) You need to load this as an application resource. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other

Comment: Thank you James_D! I now fully understand how resource lookup works. That is some detailed and easy explanation to grasp. Amazing.